# NestJS circular dependency error using Jest framework

Tags: jestjs, nestjs, circular-dependency, ts-jest

I am facing a circular dependency error. The module file is attached below. My NestJS application works and builds perfectly but when writing unit test for it, it starts to throw the circular dependency error.

**ListingService - Test Suite**

```
import { Model } from "mongoose";
import { ListingDocument, Listings } from "../schemas/listings.schema";
import { ListingsService } from "../services/listings.service"
import { Test, TestingModule } from "@nestjs/testing";
import { getModelToken } from "@nestjs/mongoose";

describe("ListingsService", () => {
    let listingsService: ListingsService;
    let mockListingDocument: Model<ListingDocument>;

    beforeEach(
        async () => {
            const moduleRef: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
                providers: [
                    ListingsService,
                    {
                        provide: getModelToken(Listings.name),
                        useValue: Model,
                    }
                ]
            }).compile();
            listingsService = moduleRef.get<ListingsService>(ListingsService);
            mockListingDocument = moduleRef.get<Model<ListingDocument>>(getModelToken(Listings.name))
            jest.clearAllMocks();
        }
    )
```

**ListingModule - Module File**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ListingsService } from './services/listings.service';
import { ListingsController } from './controllers/listings.controller';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Listings, ListingsSchema } from './schemas/listings.schema';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      { name: Listings.name, schema: ListingsSchema },
    ]),
  ],
  controllers: [ListingsController],
  providers: [ListingsService],
})
export class ListingsModule {}
```

I am expecting the test suite to work as the application is working without the circular dependency error, as there is no circular dependency between the modules. This module is not being used anywhere else in the application.

The error I receive

```
[Nest] 24660  - 27/04/2023, 3:29:08 pm     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 24660  - 27/04/2023, 3:29:08 pm   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] A circular dependency has been detected inside ListingsModule. Please, make sure that each side of a bidirectional relationships are decorated with "forwardRef()".
Error: A circular dependency has been detected inside ListingsModule. Please, make sure that each side of a bidirectional relationships are decorated with "forwardRef()".
```